# How to fix ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './config/dev .json'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm

I've got an old code which was developed on node version 8. I'm using node v16.13.0 and when I tried to run "npm install" It showed some incompatibility between the node versions, so I updated its package.json by running "ncu -u" after that I got success in installing node modules by running "npm install" but when I try to run a script "npm run start-dev" it shows me this error

> node:internal/fs/utils:344
> throw err;
> ^
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './config/dev .json'
> at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
> at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
> at loadFile (D:\My Work\development\diemnode\node_modules\convict\src\main.js:434:19)
> at D:\My Work\development\diemnode\node_modules\convict\src\main.js:597:24
> at Array.forEach ()
> at Object.loadFile (D:\My Work\development\diemnode\node_modules\convict\src\main.js:595:13)
> at Object. (D:\My Work\development\diemnode\config.js:101:8)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {   errno: -4058,   syscall: 'open',   code: 'ENOENT',   path:
> './config/dev .json' } [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file
> changes before starting...

And when I go to this directory as it says

> open './config/dev .json'

The file dev.json is already there and inside that file there is only empty brackets "{}" like this.

here's my file structure from the root

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z1D1.png)

Comment: Please provide more information about related files or folders, package.json etc.

Comment: @Batuhan I've got package.json in the root of the directory from where I'm running the script for the development environment "npm run start-dev" and the I've got another folder named "config" to store configuration files in the root of the directory. Inside that folder I have several files "dev.json" "prod.json" and the above error is referring to "dev.json" file and inside that dev.json there is only empty brackets "{ }"

Comment: Please provide an image containing folder structure and also npm scripts section as json. I understood but other viewers maybe can't imagine your structure. As a questioner be much more clear on questions. @Saad8113

Comment: @Batuhan okay I'm editing the question